# IJwhost throwing exception in C++/CLI project running .NET 7

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a Native C++ project which calls --> C++/CLR dll as Bridge --> Calls C# .Net DLL.

During runtime, my native code runs fine, but when I make my first call into the C++/CLR bridge I get the following exception:

[image]

Stack trace:
[image]

According to the modules in the debugger the dll is loaded:
[image]

Any idea on what could be the issue?

EDIT:

The issue was that I did not copy over the runtimeconfig.json file. So if anyone runs into the same issue. Make sure both the Ijwhost and runtimeconfig.json are copied over to the location of the c++ / CLR dll.

Comment: It stopped too soon to see the value of the *long*.  Press F5 to continue running, that should set an identifiable error code, reported as the process exit code.  Look in the Output window for that value.  Google the hex value of that exit code.